Mass replace of similarly named materials across whole project
I have four scenes in my project, each scene containing one model of a character. These characters are nearly identical and are meant to use the same materials for their clothes and accessories and whatnot.
What I did is that I first set up each model on a blender save and then joined them all into one super blender file. But now, since each model has its own set of materials, I'm facing this situation:

I know that I can use the 'Remap Users' button to swap materials .001 through .003 with the one that has no number suffix, but in a project with about 668 materials total, I'd rather find a way to automatize this process.
Doing some digging around other questions, other forums, and seeing what comes up in the Scripting tab of Blender, I've come to this prototype:
import re
import bpy

pattern = re.compile(r'^KK Body\.\d{3}$')
material_ids = [material.name for material in bpy.data.materials if pattern.match(material.name)]

for material_id in material_ids:
    bpy.ops.outliner.id_remap(id_type='MATERIAL', old_id=material_id, new_id='KK Body')

However, executing this code on the console gives me the following error:
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.outliner.id_remap.poll() failed, context is incorrect

And to this point, I've run out of ideas. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to run this code? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do?
Thanks a lot!

You don't have to use an operator. bpy.types.ID have a user_remap function to do it directly.
import re
import bpy

pattern = re.compile(r'^KK Body\.\d{3}$')
material_ids = [material for material in bpy.data.materials if pattern.match(material.name)]
base_material = bpy.data.materials['KK Body']

for material_id in material_ids:
    material_id.user_remap(base_material)

# OR

[material.user_remap(base_material) for material in bpy.data.materials if pattern.match(material.name)]

# OR

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if pattern.match(material.name):
        material.user_remap(base_material)


Thank you! This did exactly what I needed!
